# Why I can't create a table with this dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_CREATETABLE
(
    @newTableName NVARCHAR(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = 'create table @tableName (id int identity(1,1) primary key )'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@tableName nvarchar(200)', @newTableName
END
```

When I try to execute this:

```
EXEC SP_CREATETABLE 'NEWTABLENAME';
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '@tableName'.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_CREATETABLE
(
    @newTableName NVARCHAR(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = 'create table ' + QUOTENAME(@newTableName) + ' (id int identity(1,1) primary key )'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END

EXEC SP_CREATETABLE 'NEWTABLENAME';
```

Comment: @Prdp  How do yo prevent this: `EXEC SAIR_CREATETABLE 'NEWTABLENAME (); drop table NEWTABLENAME';`

Comment: QUOTENAME function is supposed to mitigate that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot create the table is because parameters only work for values in the query, not for table names or column names.

I often approach this using `REPLACE()`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_CREATETABLE (
    @newTableName NVARCHAR(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @sql = 'create table @tableName (id int identity(1,1) primary key )';
    SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@tableName', @newTableName);
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```